# Where to put data, to cloud storage? or web server for android?

Tags: android, gps, cloud

I want to make a project in android. Taking events from specific websites and then when a registered user opens the app, it will bring them to events nearby.

But I can not decide which storage to use , so  I can not move on.

Please help me.

From here,
http://www.itworld.com/article/2832631/cloud-computing/when-to-use-cloud-platforms-vs--dedicated-servers.html

dedicated server seems better and as it is a school project, it is also suitable. But i am not sure still.

Comment: This is an opinion-solicitation question, with no right answer. There are so many storage options, so many different cloud providers, so many database engine types... Plus we don't even know a single thing about your app (the question would still be opinion-based, but without knowing anything about your app, *any* storage could be suggested).

Comment: Also: you might be overthinking this if you "can not move on" - when it's a school project.